# SQL split conditionaly values into multiple rows

Tags: mysql, sql, delimiter, csv

I have 3 tables:

attribute:

```
attribute_id | name         | type
--------------------------------------
8            | material     | dict
9            | description  | text
10           | size         | numeric
```

dictionary:

```
dict_id | attribute_id | value
---------------------------------
101     | 8            | fabric
102     | 8            | metal
100     | 18           | example
```

product_values:

```
product_id | attribute_id | value
----------------------------------
2237       | 8            | 101,102
2237       | 9            | Lorem ipsum
2237       | 10           | 100
```

And I want output like this:

```
product_id | attribute_id | type    | value
---------------------------------------------
2237       | 8            | dict    | fabric
2237       | 8            | dict    | material
2237       | 9            | text    | Lorem ipsum
2237       | 10           | numeric | 100
```

If this is hard to achive I can modify this structure and migrate data but this is final solution.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep. Modify the structure.

Comment: If is possible I want to know

Comment: I think what you're looking for is some kind of EAV model. That model is widely frowned upon around here, because it's such a pain to maintain - but it can have its uses.